# Proving $2+\sqrt{-3}$ is a prime in $\mathbb{Z}\left[\sqrt{-3}\right]$; and proving elements prime in arbitrary rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

I just started my study in ring theory. A problem said

> Please prove that $2+\sqrt{-3}$ is a prime element of $\mathbb{Z}\left[\sqrt{-3}\right]$.

I try to prove it by definition which is *If $p$ is a prime element, when $p|ab$,then $p|a$ and $p|b$.*

I use anti-proof to say that if $p|ab$ and $p \nmid a$ and $p \nmid b$. But here I face a challenge and don't know what to do next since the upcoming calculation cannot directly get any contradiction.

If anyone can give a proof by definition, it will be better.

> Futhurmore, how can I verify whether an element is prime or not? For arbitary element in arbitary ring?

Comment: Maybe you need the norm.

Comment: Your last question is hopelessly general. Just deciding whether $p \in \mathbb Z$ remains prime in the ring of integers of an algebraic extension is a major problem in algebraic number theory.

Comment: Thanks for editing to make these questions more clear. You are right, and you comments reminds me of how hard mathematicians have tried to figure out primes in $Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prove an ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ to be prime, you may consider the quotient ring $R/I$. If this ring is a integral domain, then $I$ is
prime.

In this case,

$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]/(2+\sqrt{-3}) \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+3,2+x) \cong \mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$

and conclude $(2+\sqrt{-3})$ is prime ideal. (The last isomorphism is given by $x \mapsto -2$.)

Comment: This is fine but the OP wants a proof directly from the definition of prime.

Comment: Perhaps the OP could clarify, but I don't see anywhere in the question where they say that they want a proof directly from the definition of prime, only that they *tried* to get a proof like that and failed.

Comment: If anyone can give a proof by definition, it will be the best. For this proof, I cannot understand the first isomorphism to $Z[x]/(x^2+3,2+x)$, what is that?